# How can I add to beginning or end of a file in Perl?

Tags: perl

What is the best way of writing the some content to the beginning and end of a File in Perl

Comment: Hi Krish, you've asked a large amount of Perl questions recently which are covered by the FAQs and basic documentation. Have you read perlintro ( http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html ), perldata ( http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html ) and perlopentut ( http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html ) ?

Comment: Have I mentioned lately how much I hate the way comments deal with links?

Comment: Agreed, Telemachus. It would be nice if there were a comment preview feature too. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appending is trivial:

```
open my $fh, '>>', 'some.file' or die "Cannot open file for append: $!\n";
print $fh $some_content;
close $fh;
```

On the other hand, adding something in the beginning (or in the middle) is very complicated.

One way to do it:

```
use File::Temp qw/ tempfile /;
use File::Copy;

open my $in, '<', 'some.file' or die "Cannot open file for reading: $!\n";

my ($out, $temp_file_name) = tempfile();

print $out $some_content;
my $l;
print $out $l while defined( $l = <$in> );

close $in;
close $out;

move( $temp_file_name, 'some.file' );
```

Comment: I would tend to make a backup of the original always - just in case I screw something up in the script. Also, will `print out $l while my $l = <$in>;` work?

Comment: As for backup - you can of course. as for the while - sorry, no. I fixed it, and added proper check with defined().

Answer (score 8):

This is covered by the [FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)

Answer (score 1):

The following code is the most simple example I can think of.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
open (MYFILE, '>>data.txt');
print MYFILE "Bob\n";
close (MYFILE);
```

The '>>' tells the open function that you want to edit file by placing characters onto the end of it.

Replace this with '>' to replace the content instead.

To place the content at the beginning of the file - I would suggesting reading in the file, manually placing the content at the begging of the char array, and then writing to the file with '>'

Answer (score 0):

Use the Tie::File module and it can be done easily although it may not be the most efficient way. You can edit a file just as if it is a perl array, so to add a line to the beginning you would use unshift() and add a line to the end you can use push(). The modules documentation is pretty clear on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a [templating system](http://template-toolkit.org)?